# How to unscope default_scope in join/eager_load?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two models:

```
class User
  default_scope -> { where(deleted_at: nil) }
end

class Order 
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And I want to get orders with deleted or not deleted users:

```
Order.joins(:user).merge(User.unscoped)
Order.joins(:user).merge(User.unscope(where: :deleted_at))
# SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" 
# INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "orders"."user_id" AND "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL 
# ORDER BY "orders"."id" DESC LIMIT 1

Order.eager_load(:user).merge(User.unscoped)
Order.eager_load(:user).merge(User.unscope(where: :deleted_at))
# SELECT  "orders"."id" AS t0_r0, "orders"."user_id" AS t0_r1, 
# "users"."id" AS t1_r0, "users"."deleted_at" AS t1_r1 FROM "orders" 
# LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "orders"."user_id" AND "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL 
# ORDER BY "orders"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
```

None of these work.

Every query adds "AND "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL" into join statement.

Nothing changes if I specify association scope:

```
class Order
  belongs_to :user, -> { unscoped } 
end
```

However includes works as expected:

```
Order.includes(:user).merge(User.unscoped).last
# SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" ORDER BY "orders"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
# SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1054
```

How can I make rails to unscope association in a join?

Answer (score 5):

I solved this issue by writing join query manually. For your case it should look like:

```
Order.joins('INNER JOIN users ON users.id=orders.user_id')
```

Although `Order.includes(:user).merge(User.unscoped)`solution, that you found, looks a bit nicer, unless you really want to have only one query

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You can try like this. It works in Rails >= 3

```
User.unscoped { Order.joins(:user) }
```

Comment: It still works: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html#method-i-unscoped

Comment: Thank you. But if I have multiple relations to unscope I'd have to wrap it up multiple times. I wonder if it can be done in some other way?

Comment: This don't work in rails 6 because has a bug https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13775 . Manual join is better for now Order.joins('INNER JOIN users ON users.id=orders.user_id')

Answer (score 2):

You can define another association on same model to target specifically those deleted users:

This example works assuming you use act-as-paranoid to handle soft-deletion.

```
class Order 
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :all_user, -> { with_deleted }, foreign_key: 'user_id'
end
```

Then choose your weapons:

```
Order.includes(:user).pluck(:email)     # Only non soft-deleted emails
Order.includes(:all_user).pluck(:email) # All emails including where deleted_at is null
```

```

Comment: Not working for with_deleted in associates joins in rails4 with gem paranoid